# How do I get a top-down-shooter bullet to collide with an enemy? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, bullet

My enemies slowly move down the screen from the top of the stage, and the player is down the bottom, firing bullets. I'm having an issue with getting the bullets to actually collide with the enemy, and remove both objects from the stage?

This is my code so far:

```
for(var i = 4; i<core.numChildren; i++){
    var target:MovieClip = core.getChildAt(i);  
        if (this.hitTestObject(target)){
                        
        //remove listeners
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStart);
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
        
        //remove bullet
        core.removeChild(target);
        
        //remove zombie
        core.removeChild(this);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thankyou :)

Comment: So, what's the problem? Also **var target:MovieClip = core.getChildAt(i);** will probably not compile because **getChild** methods return **DisplayObject** type which is not assignable to **MovieClip** variable.

Comment: @Organis sorry, the problem I'm having is that the bullets do not collide with the enemy. The code in the question is from the loop function on the enemy object, which is called to the stage.

Comment: I don't see any big problems with the code itself. The most likely reason it does not do what it is expected to do is that it does not match the hierarchy of your app. Maybe bullets are not in **core**. Or maybe bullets are exactly in the bottommost 4 elements you deliberately skip.

Comment: @Organis thankyou so much for your help, I'll look into those two suggestions!